# Writing VS2010 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, contextmenu, vs-extensibility

I'd like to create an extension for Visual Studio 2010. The functionalities I need are these:

1. Add a context menu item for Project (when user right clicks project name in his solution, he'll get my context item in the list).
2. When he clicks, a new WinForms form appears, where he can input some data, and an option to save that data for future reuse.
3. When he clicks OK on that Form I'll generate some files and add those files to be a part of his project that he rightclicked.

The [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) is exactly the kind of behaviour I want to immitate in VS, but it's source was written in VS2008, and I'd like to use VS2010 Extension options which are quite changed as I understand...

I found some [resources](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx#ShellSamples) on the msdn, but I found it confusing with incomplete info (e.g. MenuAndCommands example).

Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: _'but I found it confusing with incomplete info'_ Amen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know where to point out so you can get specific examples of what you are trying to achieve. However, in the following resources you will find complete and detailed information about the overall process, and some help to achieve 1. and 2.

[VS 2010 Package Development – Chapter 1: Visual Studio Packages](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/03/02/VisualStudioPackages.aspx)

[VS 2010 Package Development – Chapter 2: Commands, Menus and Toolbars](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/05/23/vs-2010-package-development-chapter-2-commands-menus-and-toolbars.aspx)